# How to skip errors in web scraping with python?

Tags: python, exception, web-scraping

I am new in python and would like to learn web scraping with python.
My first project are the yellow pages in Germany.

When executing my code, I am getting following IndexError after scraping 12 pages:

> ('Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Zorro/PycharmProjects/scraping/venv/Lib/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg/pip/_vendor/pytoml/test.py", line 25, in 
>       city = city_container[0].text.strip()
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>
> Process finished with exit code 1')

I would like to know how I can skip this error, so that python does not stop scraping.

I tried to use try and except blocks, but did not succeed.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests


page_title = "/Seite-"
page_number = 1

for i in range(25):

my_url = "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/Branchen/Italienisches%20Restaurant/Berlin"

page_html = requests.get(my_url + page_title + str(page_number))
page_soup = soup(page_html.text, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "table"})

for container in containers:
    name_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "h2"})
    name = name_container[0].text.strip()

    street_container = container.findAll("span", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"})
    street = street_container[0].text.strip()

    city_container = container.findAll("span", {"itemprop": "addressLocality"})
    city = city_container[0].text.strip()

    plz_container = container.findAll("span", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})
    plz_name = plz_container[0].text.strip()

    tele_container = container.findAll("li", {"class": "phone"})
    tele = tele_container[0].text.strip()

    print(name, "\n" + street, "\n" + plz_name + " " + city, "\n" + tele)
    print()

page_number += 1
```

Comment: Please read [the docs about exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the formatting seems to have suffered a little upon posting the code.
Two things:

1) When webscraping it is usually advisable to add some downtime between consecutive scrapes to not get thrown off the server and not block too many resources. I added `time.sleep(5)` between every page request to wait 5 seconds before loading another page.

2) For me, `try except` worked just fine, if you add `pass` to the exception part. Of course, you can become more sophisticated in treating exceptions.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import time


page_title = "/Seite-"
page_number = 1

for i in range(25):
    print(page_number)
    time.sleep(5)
    my_url = "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/Branchen/Italienisches%20Restaurant/Berlin"

    page_html = requests.get(my_url + page_title + str(page_number))
    page_soup = soup(page_html.text, "html.parser")

    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "table"})

    for container in containers:

        try:
            name_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "h2"})
            name = name_container[0].text.strip()

            street_container = container.findAll("span", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"})
            street = street_container[0].text.strip()

            city_container = container.findAll("span", {"itemprop": "addressLocality"})
            city = city_container[0].text.strip()

            plz_container = container.findAll("span", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})
            plz_name = plz_container[0].text.strip()

            tele_container = container.findAll("li", {"class": "phone"})
            tele = tele_container[0].text.strip()

            print(name, "\n" + street, "\n" + plz_name + " " + city, "\n" + tele)
            print()

        except:
            pass

    page_number += 1
```